# Resetting Select2 component with VueJS

Tags: vuejs2

I am still learning VueJS and confused a bit. The [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/d131Lebj/) contains a basic component for Select2 (which is from their website)

```
<div id="el"></div>

<!-- using string template here to work around HTML <option> placement restriction -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="demo-template">
  <div>
    <p>Selected: {{ selected }}</p>
    <select2 :options="options" v-model="selected">
      <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
    </select2>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="select2-template">
  <select>
    <slot></slot>
  </select>
</script>
```

I am trying to add a button to reset the component to its initial state. I used Select2 but cannot use solutions I have found on Stackoverflow as they depend on jQuery. I would really appreciate any clue where to start

Answer (score 0):

What is your initial state? If it is 2 just use this:

```
<button @click="selected = 2">Reset</button>
```